# Преобразование типов и шаблоны

Tags: c++

Допустим, что есть такой класс обертка ( это может быть умный указатель к примеру ) :

```
template<class T>
class SomeTemplate
{
   SomeTemplate(T* pData);
   // .. some code
   T* getPointer() { return pData; }
private:
   T* pData;
};
```

И два таких :

```
class A
{
    // ... some code
};

class B : public A
{
   // ... some code
};
```

Так вот, бывает, что возникает ситуация когда есть

```
 SomeTemplate<B> и SomeTemplate<A> нужно бы преобразовать к SomeTemplate<B>. Конечно самый очевидный способ :

B* pTempB = (B*)pA.getPointer();
SomeTemplate<B> pB(pTempB);
```

Можно ли это сделать как - то проще ? Перегрузить оператор приведения типа у SomeTemplate
ведь тоже никак нельзя ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
template<typename S>
SomeTemplate(SomeTemplate<S>& s)
{
    pData = s.getPointer();
}
```

(ну и оператор присваивания).

Таким образом вы [сможете](http://ideone.com/HUdZLO) написать

```
SomeTemplate<Derived> d(new D());
// ...
SomeTemplate<Base> b(d);
```

В обратную сторону скомпилироваться [не должно](http://ideone.com/BcJ2rD), что на самом деле правильно: ведь указатель на базовый класс не обязательно указывает на экземпляр производного класса.